# app.config file connection string

Tags: c#, wpf, connection-string

I am developing a Outlook addin in .Net.I need to override connection string in  PojectName -> Properites -> Settings.settings and force to use connectionstring in app.comfig
Im using connection string in app.config as

Im calling this connection in all the forms as

```
public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EBM_ExinetConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    }
```

and DC as `HBMDataDataContext dc = new HBMDataDataContext(Global.GetConnectionString());`

This works perfectly fine on my local development enviornment.
But when I make msi setup and install it on production , addin is not loaded. And I m getting the error 
not loaded a runtime error occurred during the loading of the com add in.
When I reverse the code to  `HBMDataDataContext dc = new HBMDataDataContext` it works without problem.
Could anybody please help me , what Im missing here?
Thank in advance!

Comment: Have you verified that your config file is deployed correctly?

Comment: yes, it is deployed correctly